# DPM 2010 inconsistent replica all the time

Tags: scdpm

We are having problems to backup a Windows 2003 server using DPM 2010. We are backup about 40GB data but the replica will just use 90MB. it always reports the replica is inconsistent.

The latest update rollup 7 has been applied on the server and the agent version is 3.0.8195.

The error log from the agent:

> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:03:59.084    31  vsssnapshotrequestor.cpp(347)   [00C11BF0]  47775C23-0B59-4DB7-BD74-F099CF0E5090    NORMAL  CVssSnapshotRequestor::AddVolumeForSnapshot [00C11BF0]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:03:59.084    31  vsssnapshotrequestor.cpp(379)       47775C23-0B59-4DB7-BD74-F099CF0E5090    NORMAL  ssLocalVolumeGuid = [\?\Volume{b71e166a-6ff3-11db-83e4-0015c5e9b572}], ssClusterVolGuid=[\?\Volume{b71e166a-6ff3-11db-83e4-0015c5e9b572}]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:03:59.084    31  vsssnapshotrequestor.cpp(390)   [00C11BF0]  47775C23-0B59-4DB7-BD74-F099CF0E5090    NORMAL  CVssSnapshotRequestor: AddVolumeForSnapshot - Marked volume \?\Volume{b71e166a-6ff3-11db-83e4-0015c5e9b572}\ to be snapshot
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:03:59.084    31  vsssnapshotrequestor.cpp(424)   [00C11BF0]  47775C23-0B59-4DB7-BD74-F099CF0E5090    NORMAL  CVssSnapshotRequestor::StartPrepareForBackup [00C11BF0]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:03:59.131    31  vssbaserequestor.cpp(1070)  [00C11BF0]  47775C23-0B59-4DB7-BD74-F099CF0E5090    NORMAL  CVssBaseRequestor::StartGatherWriterStatus [00C11BF0]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:00.131    31  vssbaserequestor.cpp(946)   [00C11BF0]      NORMAL  QueryStatus returned 0x4230a, Releasing VssAsync [0071A280]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:00.131    31  vssbaserequestor.cpp(1103)  [00C11BF0]      NORMAL  CVssBaseRequestor::CheckWriterStatus [00C11BF0]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:00.131    31  filterwrapper.cpp(68)   [0262FC5C]      NORMAL  CreateBitmap: {74B5196F-3934-4588-B613-8618A80CA453}
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:00.131    31  vsssnapshotrequestor.cpp(529)   [00C11BF0]      NORMAL  CVssSnapshotRequestor::StartDoSnapshot [00C11BF0]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    31  vssbaserequestor.cpp(946)   [00C11BF0]      NORMAL  QueryStatus returned 0x8004231f, Releasing VssAsync [00719710]
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    31  vastatemachineutils.cpp(406)    [00BF4D28]      WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x8004231f] : F: lVal : hrStatus
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    05  fsmstate.cpp(167)   [00BB3AF0]      WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x8004231f] : F: lVal : pTransition->Execute(pEvent)
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    05  genericfsm.cpp(225) [00BB32A0]      WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x8004231f] : F: lVal : m_pCurrentState->SendEvent(pEvent, pNextState)
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    05  fsmtransition.cpp(111)  [006FFC40]      WARNING Failed: Hr: = [0x8004231f] HasEventErrorCode: completion: 0x27, signature: 0xaabbcc00
>
> 0AC8  05A4    08/22   14:04:26.215    31  aasubtask.cpp(1373) [00BB5FE8]      WARNING Updating task status with hr: 8004231f8x, dls error code:30014
>
> 0AC8  1600    08/22   14:04:26.215    31  aasubtask.cpp(913)  [00BB5FE8]      WARNING
>
> 0AC8  1600    08/22   14:04:26.215    31  aasubtask.cpp(913)  [00BB5FE8]      WARNING 0\?\Volume{b71e166a-6ff3-11db-83e4-0015c5e9b572}\D:\
>
> 0AC8  1600    08/22   14:04:26.215    03  runtime.cpp(1599)   [00B7F808]      FATAL   Subtask failure, sending status response XML=[
>
> 0AC8  1600    08/22   14:04:26.215    03  runtime.cpp(1599)   [00B7F808]      FATAL   0\?\Volume{b71e166a-6ff3-11db-83e4-0015c5e9b572}\D:\
>
> 0AC8  1600    08/22   14:04:26.215    03  runtime.cpp(1599)   [00B7F808]      FATAL   ]

Thank a lot

Regard RW

Comment: Is Windows Server Backup installed on the server to be backed up? I've seen this where you can install the DPM agent on a machine without having Windows Server Backup installed, but DPM uses WSB, and so it won't work right without WSB...

Comment: Hi Ryan, we have been using the DPM for more than two years, and that problem just happened about 4 days ago. Thanks